# Extracting Bracketed WordNet Definitions (Python)

Tags: python, wordnet

If I look up the definition of molecule synset from WordNet, I get the 2 results below:

```
================== molecule =======================
(physics and chemistry) the simplest structural unit of an element or compound
(nontechnical usage) a tiny piece of anything
```

Is there a way for me to use the bracketed notes, e.g. (physics and chemistry) so as to pick out the most relevant definition?

I've tried filtering my results based on relatedness, but the values of relatedness are not consistent.

Thanks!

***[Edit for Clarity]***

I'm building flashcards that can be used for revising the sciences (biology/ chemistry/ physics). Words that have multiple definitions are giving me trouble since I have to manually indicate the relevant synset.

For example, for "molecule", I have to specify that the result at index 0 has the definition that I want.

I'm wondering if there's a way of automatically filtering the results using the term in brackets. In this case, I'd want to avoid (nontechnical usage) and instead choose (physics and chemistry).

Comment: The relevance is quite vague term here - relevant to what? By your description I am thinking that you might want to find a sense which is the most relevant **in the current context**. This in itself is quite vague and requires precise definition (e.g. context of a sentence, surrounding words, etc.). Please add this detail so that you can be helped with the issue.